# zend framework error message when checking email against database

Tags: zend-framework

Hi friends i have added this in my form

> ```
>     $email->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists(array(
>                     //add database, table and field
>                     'adapter'=>Zend_Registry::get('zf_sandbox'),
>                     'field'=>'email',
>                     'table'=>'users'
>                     ), TRUE )
>         );
> ```

when i reload the form page in browser i get the error

> Message: No entry is registered for key 'zf_sandbox'

How do i register this please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'adapter'=>Zend_Registry::get('zf_sandbox')
```

This does not appear to be a database adapter. it seems to be a database name. 
If you are using only one database and your database adapter is setup in your *application.ini* or *bootstrap.php* then your adapter is likely set.
 At worst you have to do:
`'adapter'=>Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter(),`
Your *application.ini* will likely have your Db adapter already setup and will resemble this:

```
resources.db.adapter = "pdo_Mysql"
resources.db.params.username = "username"
resources.db.params.password = "password"
resources.db.params.dbname = "dbname"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
```